# How can I write code for use LOOP FOR , date for sum balance

Tags: oracle, plsql

**I have two table** :

> **on table is tbl_ledger with columns**

```
| balance  | eff_date    |
| -------- | --------    |
| 200$     | 2FEB 2008   |
| 500$     | 2FEB 2008   |
| 250$     | 3FEB 2008   |
| 150$     | 5feb 2008   |
```

> ANOTHER TABLE NAME IS : tbl_ledger_input
> **with columns balance and eff_date**

```
| balance  | eff_date     |
| -------- | --------     |
|700$      | 2FEB 2008    |
| 250$     | 3FEB 2008    |
| 150$     |5FEB    2008  |
| ........ | .......      |
```

**I want insert into table tbl_ledger_input for each day from tbl_ledger sum (balance) for each date with LOOP FOR
**
PLEASE HELP ME .

***I WANT INSERT INTO TABLE TBL_LEDGER_INPUT using LOOP FOR each EFF_DATE*** .

Comment: tbl_ledger_input is an aggregation of tbl_ledger, which you get with a simple select (including `SUM` and `GROUP BY`). So, what is tbl_ledger_input good for? Why not simply select the data from tbl_ledger whenever you want?

Comment: We do not use loops in SQL, because SQL is intended for set processing. Use aggregation and `insert ... select ...` instead

Comment: @astentx: While you are right that we'd rather use SQL here instead, the question seems to be how to do this with a loop in PL/SQL. I've changed the sql tag to plsql for the time being.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks, it looks more appropriate for this case. I hope that this is an assignment question, because even for PL/SQL case it should be done using `bulk collect` and `forall ... insert ...`.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already seen in comments, loop isn't *the best* choice for that. Row-by-row processing is slow; you won't notice any difference if you're dealing with small data sets (as in this example), though.

If you want to do it in PL/SQL (using a loop), a simple option is a cursor `FOR` loop:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select eff_date, sum(balance) balance
  3                  from tbl_ledger
  4                  group by eff_date
  5                 )
  6    loop
  7      insert into tbl_ledger_input (balance, eff_date)
  8        values (cur_r.balance, cur_r.eff_date);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From tbl_ledger_input;

   BALANCE EFF_DATE
---------- -----------
       700 02-FEB-2008
       250 03-FEB-2008
```

What you should really be doing is

```
SQL> truncate table tbl_ledger_input;

Table truncated.

SQL> insert into tbl_ledger_input (balance, eff_date)
  2  select sum(balance), eff_date
  3  from tbl_ledger
  4  group by eff_date;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * From tbl_ledger_input;

   BALANCE EFF_DATE
---------- -----------
       700 02-FEB-2008
       250 03-FEB-2008

SQL>
```

Comment: that is Great ,very very thank you