# How can use for loop in left join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a tbl_ledger_input table that has a number of columns that I want to be inserted in the
tbl_ledger_branch table finnaly. But the column balance value may be null on some days. For example,
if the balance value is null on April 2 eff_date column, it should be entered from the balance
value of the previous day. The idea is that I join the table with itself according to the code below

```
select
a.ledger_code , a.ref_cur_id , a.ref_branch,a.balance,
b.ledger_code  ,b.ref_cur_id, b.ref_branch ,b.balance

from  (select * from tbl_ledger_input where eff_date = '06-APR-21' ) a  

left join  (select * from tbl_ledger_input where eff_date = '07-APR-21') b

on  a.ledger_code = b.ledger_code  and  

a.ref_cur_id = b.ref_cur_id  and a.ref_branch = b.ref_branch  

where b.ledger_code is null

order by  a.ledger_code , a.ref_cur_id , 
a.ref_branch,b.ledger_code  ,
b.ref_cur_id, b.ref_branch
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nMNe.png)

, but I have shown only one day's data in the output, now I want to write a for loop for the days in
the range,
thank you for your help, please

```
select
a.ledger_code , a.ref_cur_id , a.ref_branch,a.balance,
NVL(b.ledger_code , a.ledger_code ) , 
NVL(b.ref_cur_id ,a.ref_cur_id ) , NVL(b.ref_branch ,a.ref_branch ) , 
NVL(b.balance , a.balance )




from  (select * from tbl_ledger_input where eff_date = '06-APR-21' ) a 

 left join  (select * from tbl_ledger_input where eff_date = '07-APR-21') b

on  a.ledger_code = b.ledger_code  and  a.ref_cur_id = b.ref_cur_id  and a.ref_branch = 
b.ref_branch  

where b.ledger_code is null

order by  a.ledger_code , a.ref_cur_id , a.ref_branch,b.ledger_code  ,
b.ref_cur_id, b.ref_branch ;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data (as text, not images); an English description (not code) of the logic that you want to implement; details of the issues/errors with your code; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment you talk about a range of dates but your image (don't use images) does not show any dates and your code only uses hard-coded strings so it is unclear where this range would come from and what your expected output would be.

Comment: SQL does not use `FOR` loops. What you probably want is a row-generator (either a hierarchical query or a recursive query) to generate a calendar and then maybe use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` or the `LAG` analytic function but without more details of the problem it is almost impossible to do anything other than to guess.

Comment: You ask the same question for at least the third time ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444551/how-can-i-write-code-for-use-loop-for-date-for-sum-balance), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518696/how-can-i-use-for-loop-for-date-in-oracle)) and every time there are comments about `for` loop in SQL. Can you please clarify the difference between this question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518696/how-can-i-use-for-loop-for-date-in-oracle) combining all the answers you have for all previous questions?

Comment: @astentx I was not allowed to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sample data would be like here:

```sql
--  Sample data:
WITH
    tbl_ledger_input (LEDGER_CODE, EFF_DATE, REF_CUR_ID, REF_BRANCH, BALANCE) AS
        (   Select 8011, To_Date('02.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, 200000.00 From Dual  Union All
            Select 8011, To_Date('03.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, 300000.00 From Dual  Union All
            Select 8011, To_Date('04.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, 400000.00 From Dual  Union All
            Select 8011, To_Date('05.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, null      From Dual  Union All
            Select 8011, To_Date('06.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, 500000.00 From Dual  Union All
            Select 8011, To_Date('07.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, null      From Dual  Union All
            Select 8011, To_Date('08.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, 800000.00 From Dual  Union All
            Select 8011, To_Date('09.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, 5751, 900000.00 From Dual
        )
```

and if you want to fill in the null values of a BALANCE column then you can use [LAG() or LEAD()](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions) analytic function to get the value from previous or next row respectively. Just take care of OVER() part to have correct Partition By and Order by clauses.
It would be something like this:

```sql
--  Main SQL
SELECT      t.EFF_DATE, 
            t.LEDGER_CODE, 
            t.REF_CUR_ID, t.REF_BRANCH, 
            t.BALANCE, 
            CASE WHEN t.BALANCE Is Null THEN LAG(t.BALANCE) OVER(Partition By t.LEDGER_CODE Order By t.LEDGER_CODE, t.EFF_DATE) END "PREVIOUS_ROW_BALANCE",
            CASE WHEN t.BALANCE Is Null THEN LEAD(t.BALANCE) OVER(Partition By t.LEDGER_CODE Order By t.LEDGER_CODE, t.EFF_DATE) END "NEXT_ROW_BALANCE"
FROM       tbl_ledger_input t -- ON (Nvl(t.EFF_DATE, d.WRK_DATE) = d.WRK_DATE)
WHERE      t.EFF_DATE Between &DATE_START And &DATE_END
ORDER BY   LEDGER_CODE, EFF_DATE

--  R e s u l t :
EFF_DATE  LEDGER_CODE REF_CUR_ID REF_BRANCH    BALANCE PREVIOUS_ROW_BALANCE NEXT_ROW_BALANCE
--------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------------
04-APR-21        8011          4       5751     400000                                       
05-APR-21        8011          4       5751                          400000           500000 
06-APR-21        8011          4       5751     500000                                       
07-APR-21        8011          4       5751                          500000           800000 
08-APR-21        8011          4       5751     800000
```

The result is for dates between 04-apr-21 and 08-apr-21 entered as parameters &DATE_START and &DATE_END
If I get your question right there is no need for any joins at all...
Additionaly, if you want the filled column BALANCE (when null) then you can do it this way (with comment):

```sql
SELECT      t.EFF_DATE, 
            t.LEDGER_CODE, 
            t.REF_CUR_ID, t.REF_BRANCH, 
            CASE WHEN t.BALANCE Is Null THEN LAG(t.BALANCE) OVER(Partition By t.LEDGER_CODE Order By t.LEDGER_CODE, t.EFF_DATE) ELSE t.BALANCE END "BALANCE",
            CASE WHEN t.BALANCE Is Null THEN 'Value from previous row' END "COMMENT"
FROM       tbl_ledger_input t 
WHERE      t.EFF_DATE Between &DATE_START And &DATE_END
ORDER BY   LEDGER_CODE, EFF_DATE

EFF_DATE  LEDGER_CODE REF_CUR_ID REF_BRANCH    BALANCE COMMENT               
--------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
04-APR-21        8011          4       5751     400000                         
05-APR-21        8011          4       5751     400000 Value from previous row 
06-APR-21        8011          4       5751     500000                         
07-APR-21        8011          4       5751     500000 Value from previous row 
08-APR-21        8011          4       5751     800000
```

Resulting datasets (either of the two) could be used for inserting the data into your tbl_ledger_branch table...

Comment: @d r
 thank you a lot lovely d r , yes ,my problem has been solved with your helping . thank you a lot dear :)

Comment: @sami You are welcome, and, if this is realy the right answer, you could accept or upvote it or both...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you have a series of calendar dates for which you have balances for some accounts. Suppose that the dates are between 1-apr-2021 and 30-apr-2021. And if for account x you have a balance bal_x on 4-apr-2021 and then you no longer have balances for all the other calendar dates that would mean that before 4-apr-2021, the balance for account x is zero, and for all the days after 4-apr-2021, the balance for account x is bal_x. Is this right?
If what I describe above is your business case and you need the balance for any accunt in that given period, I think you should treat that like below:

```
with tb_d1 as (
select max(eff_date) last_dt, min(eff_dt) first_dt
from tbl_ledger_input
)
,tb_dates as (
 select first_dt+level-1 eff_date
 from tb_d1
 connect by level<=last_dt-first_dt
 )
 ,tb_accounts as (
 select distinct ledger_code , ref_cur_id , ref_branch
 from tbl_ledger_input
 )
 select acc.ledger_code , acc.ref_cur_id , acc.ref_branch
   ,dt.eff_date
   ,coalesce(bal.balance,
      lag(bal.balance,1,0) over 
        (partition by acc.ledger_code, acc.ref_curr_id, acc.ref_branch
         order by bal.ref_date)) account_balance
 from tb_accounts acc
 cross join tb_dates dt
 left join tbl_ledger_input bal on acc.ledger_code=bal.ledger_code
   and acc.ref_curr_id=bal.ref_curr_id and acc.ref_branch=bal.ref_branch
   and dt.eff_date=bal.ref_date
 ;
```